# GZIPInputStream incomplete decompression

Tags: java, linux

The code is working fine on my laptop(JAVA 1.7) but when i run the same code on Linux server (JAVA 1.6), it doesn't work properly.

```
Java -Version
java version "1.6.0_22"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10.9) (rhel-1.28.1.10.9.el5_8-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)
```

The BufferedReader only returns 1 line of string(header) but the gz file has more than 1 line.

*The gz file is not damaged or corrupted.

*Code is fine if i load the "file" inside the gz file.

*I modify the code a bit for debug testing

```
GZIPInputStream gzip =  new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));

Reader decoder = new InputStreamReader(gzip,"ISO-8859-1"); 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(decoder);

String line = null;
String header = null;

//read 1st line of file which is file header
header = br.readLine();

System.out.println(header);

line = br.readLine();
System.out.println(line);
line = br.readLine();
System.out.println(line);
```

and it returns

IDþfirstnameþlastname

null

null

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Does your laptop also run Linux? Have you double-checked the charset?

Comment: Thanks for comment. I fixed it by using 3rd party library jgz. I think it is because of the bug on GZIPInputStream before JDK 1.7.